# actionbarsherlock on android 4.3 wont hide the bottom action bar properly, it shows blank white space instead

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-4.3-jelly-bean

Hi I am using actionbarsherlock and splitActionBarWhenNarrow to to get a bottom action bar with my menu information. I have set windowActionBarOverlay to be true.

In android 4.2 and below calling getSupportActionBar().hide(); will properly hide both the top and bottom action bars. In android 4.3 getSupportActionBar().hide() hides the top action bar properly but it leaves a blank white space where the bottom action bar use to be.

Can anyone help me with this?